# How do I get my bot to join a thread in Discord and respond

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have built a bot that will respond to a message that contains a number between 1 and 10 following a plus sign. For example +1 .. the bot responds with Total=1

However I want it to join a specific thread within Discord. It so far has not joined that thread and instead responds within the #general channel.

Below is what I believe to be the relevant section of code and the error message I am getting:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user.name} (ID: {client.user.id})')
    channel = client.fetch_channel(threadidhere)
    thread = await channel.fetch_message(threadidhere)
    await thread.join()
    async for msg in channel.history(limit=200):
```

Error:

`Ignoring exception in on_ready Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event await coro(*args, **kwargs) File "/app/bot.py", line 9, in on_ready thread = await channel.fetch_message(threadidhere) AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'fetch_message' /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py:350: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.fetch_channel' was never awaited pass RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

I have tried various methods with on_ready and none tried so far have the bot utilzing the thread.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message is - unsurprisingly - telling you exactly what the issue is & what you have to do about it

> thread = await channel.fetch_message(threadidhere) AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'

So `channel` is actually a `coroutine`, not a `Channel` instance. The next line in the error tells you why:

> **coroutine 'Client.fetch_channel' was never awaited**

```py
    channel = client.fetch_channel(threadidhere)  # <- fetch_channel
           # ^ never awaited
    thread = await channel.fetch_message(threadidhere)
                 # ^ "channel" is a coroutine here instead of a Channel instance
                 # because of the line above
```